# Dell Inspirion 15 Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I am new to Windows 8 and very displeased. I have a Windows 7 64-bit ultimate installation disk, and would like to install it on to my new Dell laptop as well as keep Windows 8 if possible, because I am an IT student. However, I want to know how to keep Windows 8 on a different partition, if necessary, but run Windows 7 without interference.

Comment: If its just the 'start screen' that's the issue, there's a few great start menu replacements that you could use. Once you get over the learning curve, windows 8 isn't that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Just create a seperate partition using Disk Management or use your existing partition to other than Windows 8 partition to install Windows 7.

Note, the partition will be formatted before installation. Then you can dual boot.

Refer this : http://lifehacker.com/5840387/how-to-dual+boot-windows-7-and-windows-8-side-by-side

Another alternative is to use Hyper-V which will allow you to run Win 7 inside 8

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to the `UEFI` with <kbd>F2</kbd> and set the option `Load Legacy Option ROM` to `true` and `Secure Boot` to `disabled` on my Dell 15R SE. Otherwise Windows 7 freezes at boot.

Now follow the steps *Ajay* posted.